# How to turn-on statistics through the session?

Tags: postgresql

I want to turn on:

- logging
- pg_stat_statements
- auto_explain extension

I know how to do it with configuration file, but how (if it's possible) to do it through my connection - I mean SQL statements, some directives, so that my steps are something like this:

1. connect to DB
2. execute some statements
3. now all queries are auto-explained in the concrete log file which I passed somewhere in 2., their statistics is collecting in `pg_stat_statements` table

How to achieve it? Is it possible? The initial state is: no logging at all, no auto_explain, to pg_stat_statements loaded/enabled.

PS. I have only one idea, to modify the configuration file from my app and then to call something like `select pg_reload_conf();` but I am not sure that it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this using `ALTER SYSTEM`:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET shared_preload_libraries = 'pg_stat_statements,auto_explain';
```

Then you need to restart the database, so that the changed `shared_preload_libraries` can take effect.

Then change these two:

```
ALTER SYSTEM SET auto_explain.log_min_duration = 0;
ALTER SYSTEM SET pg_stat_statements.track = all;
SELECT pg_reload_conf();
```

Comment: I get `unrecognized configuration parameter \"pg_stat_statements.track\"`, also `unrecognized configuration parameter \"auto_explain.log_min_duration\"`. I have PostgreSQL 12

Comment: But when I load pg_stat_statement only with `alter system set` and `auto_explain` with `load 'auto_explain'` then 2nd `alter system set auto_expl...` works OK, but the last - 3rd statement still fails with `unrecognized configuration parameter...`

Comment: Then you must do these two after the restart of the database, sorry.

Comment: yeah, really, restart. Also `kill -HUP <PID>` helps (for Docker it is PID=1). You are right, 10x